# Driver Class Not Returning Values - Python

Tags: python, class

My Python Class is not returning any values from using a driver to test. Is there anything wrong? All of the files are in the same folder and other similar classes are able to run and produce values. 
Class:

```
class Person:

#Initializer
    def __init__(self, first_name='', last_name='', phone_number='', address=None, social_sec_num='', emailAddress=''):
        self.setFirstName(first_name)
        self.setLastName(last_name)
        self.setPhoneNumber(phone_number)
        self.setAddress(address)
        self.setSocialSecNum(social_sec_num)
        self.setEmailAddress(emailAddress)

#Mutator
    def setFirstName(self, first_name):
        self.__first_name = first_name

    def setLastName(self, last_name):
        self.__last_name = last_name

    def setPhoneNumber(self, phone_number):
        self.__phone_number = phone_number

    def setAddress(self, address):
        self.__address = address

    def setSocialSecNum(self, social_sec_number):
        self.__social_sec_num = social_sec_num

    def setEmailAddress(self, emailAddress):
        self.__emailAddress = emailAddress

#Accessor Methods
    def getFirstName(self):
        return self.__first_name

    def getLastName(self):
        return self.__last_name

    def getPhoneNumber(self):
        return self.__phone_number

    def getAddress(self):
        return self.__address

    def getSocialSecNum(self):
        return self.__social_sec_num

    def getEmailAddress(self):
        return self.__emailAddress

#String Representation
    def __str__(self):

        people_string = \
        "First Name: %s" %self.getFirstName() + "\n" +\
        "Last Name: %s" %self.getLastName() + "\n" +\
        "Phone Number: %s" %self.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" +\
        "Address: %s" %self.getAddress() + "\n" +\
        "Social Security Number: %s" %self.getSocialSecNum() + "\n" +\
        "Email Address: %s" %self.getEmailAddress()

        return people_string
```

Driver:

```
from PersonHierarchy import Person
import Address

def main():

    p1 = Person("Nick", "D", "215-000-0000", Address("717 Test", "Test", "Texas", 75181), "000-00-0000", "test@test.com")
    print(p1)   
main()
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: This pattern is not very idiomatic in Python (getter/setter). If you absolutely must have them (often you don't) take a look at the [`property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: There's at least one error: `setSocialSecNum` has an argument called `social_sec_number` but inside the function body tries to use `social_sec_num`. Indeed, after fixing that error, this works as expected for me in Python 3.4.3, and also in Python 2.7.10. At first I thought maybe there was a difference between how a lack of a `__repr__` method is handled in the two versions, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @Mr.F After fixing this it returned
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PersonHierarchyTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "PersonHierarchyTest.py", line 8, in main
    p1 = Person("Nick", "D", "215-000-0000", Address("717 Test", "Test", "Texas", 75181), "000-00-0000", "test@test.com")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: maybe use `from Address import Address`  or `Address.Address(...)`